# Bootstrap inline form

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page here to illustrate my question.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/bootstrap-form/

It's a simple 2 column layout with a form in the right column

The form is in 2 columns also.

I would like the form columns to be half the with of the column it's in.

So the name input would be half the with of the right column and email input would be the remaining half.

How do I code this using bootstrap.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">

            <head>  
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="description" content="">
                <meta name="keywords" content="">
                <meta name="robots" content="">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

                <!--jQuery-->
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <!--css-->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

                <style>

                    .box{
                        height: 500px;
                    }

                    .left{
                        background: #aaa;
                    }

                    .right{
                        background: #ccc;
                        padding: 50px 0 0 0;
                    }

                </style>


                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->

                <title>Title of the document</title>
            </head>

        <body>

            <div class="wrap">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6 left box">

                        </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-6 right box">

                            <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input type="text" placeholder="name" class="form-control">

                                    <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="form-control">

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input type="text" placeholder="phone number" class="form-control">

                                    <input type="text" placeholder="company" class="form-control">

                                </div>


                            </form> 


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.form-inline .form-control
{
    width: 100%;
}
    </style>
```

and change some classes

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6 left box"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 right box">
            <form class="form-inline col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control col-sm-6" placeholder="name"
                    type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control col-sm-6" placeholder="email"
                    type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control col-sm-6" placeholder=
                    "phone number" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control col-sm-6" placeholder="company"
                    type="text">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Let me know if it works

Happy Coding !!!

[image]